Unit tests and code coverage tool for GLSL compute shaders
I use some compute shaders for some GPGPU usage. Each method of each shader must have unit tests. These unit tests must cover more than 95% of the code.
I am looking for tools that I can use to write GLSL unit tests and guarantee that my unit tests have such coverage.
